# Powershell to monitor disk usage - performance of script query

Tags: powershell, size, disk

I have the following powershell i am developing to report on my disk usage, and give me an idea overtime of which folders are changing in size, etc...

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\" | 
Select-Object Name,
    @{ 
        Name="Size";
        Expression=
            { 
                [Math]::Round(
                    ((($_ | Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Measure-Object -Sum Length).Sum + 0) / 1GB)
                    , 2)
            }
    }
```

This script is really slow...why?

does Measure-object evaluate size each time it looks at a folder?

What would be a better way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are listing each file system object on C drive and measuring its size, that can take very long time to complete. Two alternatives (there are more):

```
(Get-PSDrive c).Used/1gb

- and -

$cDrive = (New-Object -ComObject Scripting.FileSystemObject).GetDrive('C')
$used = ($cDrive.TotalSize-$cDrive.FreeSpace)/1gb
$used.ToString('N2')
```